# notify-send cause invalid number of options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, notifications

I want to do this

```
while read line
do
    echo $line;
    notify-send $line;
done < "0.txt"
```

where 0.txt is some file with 10 rows

But the problem is

```
notify-send $line;
```

causes Invalid number of options, and

```
notify-send "aasdasdsd"
```

works just fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**bash** do [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) before [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting).

```
notify-send "$line"
```

Comment: it works great, if is not hard for you can you please give me brief explain why is like this ?, thanks

Comment: [helpful link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: @Lukap: It's part of the design of the language. Some would say unfortunately, since it encourages creating filenames and strings with only `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`, while making some few operations (like `for file in $paths` easier (if you don't have special file names) since you don't have to tokenize the string. Bash didn't use to have support for arrays, which fix most of the looping issues.